# iZettle reader 2 payment

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, payment, reader

Does anyone know if it's possible to connect to a **iZettle reader 2** and make payments, using javascript? I know that there is a PHP package available to create products and make purchases etc. but i created an webbased app which is in use on android devices and from within that webbased app they want me to make it possible to connect to the **iZettle reader 2** via bluetooth and directly make it possible to pay.

I've searched for hours but i start to think that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be impossible (i've got a reply from iZettle).